# MakeFile Example

Tags: makefile

main.c: simple 'driver' program to call the 'sayHello()' function in the hello module.  Note that since main.c does not call any standard I/O
    library functions, it should not have #include stdio.h

hello.h: provides the prototype for the sayHello() function; don't forget
    the include guard

hello.c: implements the sayHello() function.  This is the only file that has
    #include stdio.h

Here is my Makefile: (w/o the 'pack' part)

```
hello: hello.o main.o
    gcc main.o hello.o -o hello
main.o: main.c hello.h
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o
hello.o: hello.c hello.h
    gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
test: hello
    ./hello
clean:
    rm -f *.o hello
```

My hello.c file is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "main.c"
int main()
{
    sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

My hello.h file is:

```
void sayHello(void);
```

My main.c file is:

```
#include "hello.h"
void sayHello(void)
{
    puts("Hello,World!");
    return;
}
```

I did a test with this and it displayed "Hello, World!". But when I ran it again just in case, there were errors. Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help to know what and how to ask questions, here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should invoke `sayHello()` from `main.c` and implement this routine in `hello.c`.

Answer (score 1):

`hello.c` and `hello.h` are some kind of library. `hello.h` provides `sayHello()` function to the world and this function is implemented in `hello.c`. That means that `hello.c` must have following include:

```
#include "hello.h"
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

`main.c` should only have:

```
#include "hello.h"
```

I think "guard" should be a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) in `hello.h`:

```
void sayHello(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking several questions without realizing it.

Let's look at it one by one. Your assignment is to make a project, separate the program which calls a function and the implementation of the function into separate pieces of source code. That's why you have the restriction on #include and the specification of the include file. You're also asked to generate a Makefile to compile the various source code files into a single program and provide basic facilities like compressing source code into a zip file or removing the object files. The assignment is meant to acquaint you with modular and automated compilation and separation of functions into distinct pieces.

If you want to learn about programming the best thing you can do is invest some effort into looking at simple make files and compilation. I could give you the answer but won't until you've tried for a while. You'll learn more from failed attempts than peeking at the answers.

In short, you have to first create the source code, figure out how to separate the sayHello function and the main function into two different source files and export the function definition through the include file. The second problem you have is the design of the make file, which your assignment pretty much specifies, all you have to do is learn about the make file configuration language and re-write the human worded specification into the make format. You'll benefit from searching for "makefile tutorial" and reading the first handful of results. ... I'm assuming you want to learn all of this and not just get the answers for no work. Although make files can be tricky, the good news is that at this level they're pretty trivial.

PS Try looking here: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: I think I am on to something. Do I just post what I have here?

Comment: Sure, go ahead, I think you might want to add it to your question, but I don't know the SO rules that well.

Comment: @user3267385 So far it looks okay, other than you don't have a "pack" target. Oh, and the best thing is to test it in action.